# maigc-wand-js not selecting borders properly

Tags: javascript, image-processing, html5-canvas

I am using [magic-wand-js](https://github.com/Tamersoul/magic-wand-js) and I wanted the selected area to get colored but I've observed it's not selecting the borders from right and bottom of area we select. Although I am calling floodFill with borders as true.

```
mask = MagicWand.floodFill(image, x, y, currentThreshold, old, true);
```

Here complete code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uhsebvL8/6/)
Can be seen clearly by uploading this image, for example select the yellow box in it and click on 'Create polygons by current selection' button, you would see a yellow line remain at bottom and right.

[image: uploadedImage]

Comment: The question is asking for a fix in 3rd party code. The Author/s of magic-wand.js already have this issue addressed in their guthub repository. https://github.com/Tamersoul/magic-wand-js/issues/5

Comment: They have added parameter includeBorders to floodFill for that, and I did have passed it as true but it seems the mask it's creating is still missing 1px from right and bottom.